React native build error: Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'
Im trying to start an android react native project from a windows 11 machine using visual studio code.
Npx react-native doctor gives all green.
But when I tried to run it, it fails on react-native-reanimated or react-native-screens libraries giving back this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

    [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using C:\Projects\artwell-nl\artwell-m\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [prefab] failed while executing:
          @echo off
          "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17\\bin\\java" ^
            --class-path ^
            "C:\\Users\\LeroyGabri�lse\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.google.prefab\\cli\\2.0.0\\f2702b5ca13df54e3ca92f29d6b403fb6285d8df\\cli-2.0.0-all.jar" ^
            com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt ^
            --build-system ^
            cmake ^
            --platform ^
            android ^
            --abi ^
            arm64-v8a ^
            --os-version ^
            21 ^
            --stl ^
            c++_shared ^
            --ndk-version ^
            23 ^
            --output ^
            "C:\\Users\\LEROYG~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\agp-prefab-staging2212317717993607799\\staged-cli-output" ^
            "C:\\Users\\LeroyGabri�lse\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\7ccf6ccbad76ec9c20b5200208893a87\\transformed\\jetified-react-android-0.72.11-debug\\prefab" ^
            "C:\\Users\\LeroyGabri�lse\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\34c2120d0d3cd8dc97826fc02c9e8fc4\\transformed\\jetified-fbjni-0.3.0\\prefab" ^
            "C:\\Users\\LeroyGabri�lse\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\0224abc76af12fc776fe75784a9fa432\\transformed\\jetified-hermes-android-0.72.11-debug\\prefab"
        from C:\Projects\artwell-nl\artwell-m\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt

I'm using:
JDK: 17.0.12
NDK: 23
Android Studio Koala.
Android SDK 33.0.3
Gradle 8.0.1
Node v20.14.0
CMake 3.22.

1
I've searched on the internet why this happens but nothing seems to work. I tried reinstalling all software.deleting node_modules, deleting .gradle folder. Installing different version of the 2 packages mentioned above.
When removing these packages it builds an puts a app on my phone, but I need those packages
Somebody understand this error message?
Im expecting it to run on my phone

The answer is on the last line. You're missing a class. Is it really "AppKt"?
